# Self-hosted browser-based remote desktop script?

Tags: remote-access

I need a self-hosted browser based remote desktop script that will connect me from any PC to my work PC. I need to either host this script within my own dedicated hosting or on my work PC. The PC that I need to remote into is always the one PC (Win7) and the IP never changes, and I have access to the Router/Firewall within.

I have tried many remote desktop services and applications - LogMeIn, Team Viewer, (Ultra/Tight) VNC, GoToMyPC and iTeleport Connect and even Windows Remote Desktop - and the web services (or ports) are blocked at whatever free wi-fi/hotel/coffee shop I am at. Note that I will need to be able to access this from any PC, so I won't be able to install any applications (or use any portable software) - hence my thinking that it will need to be browser based on a standard (not blocked) port.

If I can set up a web based remote desktop application - really a homebrew LogMeIn - then I should solve my problem.

What is the best option here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using (Ultra/Tight) VNC and changing the port that it runs on to port 81. You could then set up a web server using a Java based vnc viewer. (Download the Java VNC viewer from http://tightvnc.com/download.php)

If the computers you plan on accessing your remote machine from don't have java on them, you could use this flash based viewer, available at: http://flashlight-vnc.sourceforge.net/

If you need a solution that uses pure html5 with no addons (like flash or java) then you could try noVNC, but it takes more time and effort to set it up on the server.
http://kanaka.github.io/noVNC/

I hope this helps!

Comment: I'd run it on port 80 and use some virtual hosting with a subdomain if it's already used, and/or to actually host the applet (Java won't allow connecting to another host name). Port 81 might just as well not be on a whitelist.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [jrDesktop](http://jrdesktop.sourceforge.net/)?  Since it can be deployed as an applet, it should do what you want.  It also seems to have SSL support.

FYI, if you are using this from any unsecured computer to a work computer, there is always a risk that security can be compromise due to background process such as key loggers (to name only one potential security issue).

Disclaimer: I have not used or endorse this product, except so far as that it's open source *(win)*.

Comment: I'll try the portable version as a backup, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [Chrome Remote Desktop](https://remotedesktop.google.com/?pli=1) could be a solution :

> The app allows users to take control of a computer remotely and
>   securely, all within a Chrome window.
>
> The app uses a secure one-time code to allow access to the host
>   computer. Both computers must have the app installed to function. The
>   system is designed to work cross-platform on Mac, PC, and Linux.
>
> Available for download from the [Chrome App Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp).

[image]

Comment: @rlsaj Does this answer not satisfy the requirements? If not, why?

Comment: This might work, but it does need UDP traffic on a range of ports (or 12400-12409 [when configured so](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2799701)), and TCP on ports 443 (HTTPS) and 5222 (XMPP). Also, it needs one to be able to run Chrome *and* install the app in it, which might clash with *"I won't be able to install any applications (or use any portable software)"*.

Comment: @Arjan: Might be better off using the open source Chrome extension [Dead Simple Screen Sharing](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dead-simple-screen-sharin/gmeaegdjafdijoakhldgcifhhffdahij?hl=en), built only with HTML5, CSS3, Javascript.

Comment: @dtmland - Arjan is correct, I cannot assume that Chrome browser is installed on any computer that I may be using. A good option though harrymc for when I do have access to Chrome. Thanks.

Comment: @Arjan - thanks, although I just gave it a test and it looks like I have to enable Dead Simple Screen Sharing every time I open Chrome Browser on my server pc - which is something that I could easily forget.

Comment: If you have a problem with ports, you might use a VPN that routes all ports through one port.

Answer (score -1):

Your scenario sounds like perfect for a VPN setup. If you could find a VPN client that is able to connect to your router and opens up a secure connection to the network behind, you should have no issued accessing your PC.

From my experience VPN connection will work most of the time and are not blocked by other providers.

Comment: Isn't VPN often blocked on free Wifi hotspots?

Comment: @iltempo: VPN will be blocked from my locations.